# How to query the gap to find out that the child table cycles cover the whole period of parent table cycles

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the two tables for customer contract cycles table and customer contract location cycles table.

Customer Contract Cycles Table (PARENT Table1)

```
ID         Customer_ID     Contract_ID    START_DATE    END_DATE
5215436    128             569            2/1/2015      6/25/2017
```

Customer Contract Location Cycles Table (CHILD Table2)

```
ID          Customer_ID   Client_ID   LOCATION_ID CUSTOMER_CONTRACT_CYCLE_ID    START_DATE  END_DATE
37361952     128          284187      3477623       5215436                     2/1/2015    12/31/2016
112243088    128          284187      3477623       5215436                     1/1/2017    6/25/2017
```

The ID column from Table1 is the foreign key in table2 as CUSTOMER_CONTRACT_CYCLE_ID column is the

In my example, there are two customer contract location cycles for single customer contract and two location cycles cover the entire customer contract cycle for a same `(Customer_ID, Client_ID, LOCATION_ID, CUSTOMER_CONTRACT_CYCLE_ID)`. There is no gap between the parent and child cycles and multiple child cycle covers the entire customer contract cycle. But I would like to find out those Customer Contract Location Cycles which does not entirely cover for the Customer Contract Cycle for a given `(Customer_ID, Client_ID, LOCATION_ID, CUSTOMER_CONTRACT_CYCLE_ID)`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look for four cases:

- No locations at all for a cycle (no rows located in locations table).
- Missing starting location for a cycle (compare location to cycle start).
- Missing ending location for a cycle (compare location to cycle end).
- Missing middle location for a cycle (comparison between adjacent locations).

The following query searches for all four cases:

```
with 
s (id, start_date, end_date, ls, le, prev_end, next_start) as (
  select
    c.id,
    l.start_date, 
    l.end_date,
    lag(end_date) over(partition by c.id order by l.start_date),
    lead(start_date) over(partition by c.id order by l.start_date)
  from customer_contract_cycles c
  left join customer_contract_location_cycles l
            on c.id = l.customer_contract_cycle_id
)
select 'no locations at all for the cycle' as message, id, start_date, end_date
from s
where ls is null or le is null
union all

select 'no location at start of cycle', id, start_date, end_date
from s
where prev_end is null and le <> start_date
union all

select 'no location at end of cycle', id, start_date, end_date
from s
where next_start is null and le <> end_date
union all

select 'no location in middle of cycle', id, start_date, end_date
from s
where next_start is not null and next_start <> le + 1
```

Comment: the the query is not returning the results instead its saying columns ambiguously defined

Answer (score 0):

Speaking from experience: If you have the opportunity to do so, redefine `end_date`.
In your example the `end_date` is 31st of december and the next `start_date` is 1st of januari. Two *different* dates that, in reality, mean the *same thing*: Didn't the first Customer Contract Location Cycle continue up until the *entire* 31st of december, so right until the 1st of januari?

When defining periods using `start`+`end`, it makes calculations and filters much easier if you define the `end_date` to be **just after** the actual end.
Sometimes a notation of `[start_date, end_date[` is used: `end_date` is *not* included in the period.

Once your data is set up like that, you can simply do `where previous.end_date = next.start_date`. This also allows you to use simple indexes (instead of a function based index on `end_date+1`).

An alternative would be to learn about the **Interval datatype**. By defintion it defines a length of time: Use a `start_date`-field and a `duration`-field instead of `start_date, end_date`.
Subtracting dates, like `next.start_date - previous.start_date` returns an interval, so you can filter on `next.start_date-previous.start_date <= prevous.duration` for example.

What I want to teach you, is that modelling your data differently, can make the programming a lot easier afterwards.

Comment: Can anyone else help me with the query ?